# How do I send a real cookie with c#?

Tags: c#, cookies

This is the content of a cookie got through fiddler.
I've just edited some values.

How can I contact a webserver and login using this cookie?

```
__cfduid=d20ed7b400843304;
__gads=ID=778240b8ad7:T=407348:S=ALNI_MatBU2iOvQ3Gb0MAEN-P7fPp-ug;
ChattaMessagesUID=72472;
ChattaMessagesCurrentTalk=;
ChattaMessagesChatNotificationSoundDisabled=;
__utma=37382.34333.4073837.4287477.4288303.;
__utmc=37382;
__utmz=37382.4073837...utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
__unam=3f2073-488a8e44a-202dc74-84;
ChattaMessagesOpenedChats=33243||0;
ChattaMessagesChatTalkListStartIndex=0;
ChattaMessagesChatActiveTalkId=0;
authCookie=40734003E300A4B7DD434A407;
ASP.NET_SessionId=zprgxvfxgort24ey3jas4
```

I guess I should use something similar but I haven't found a clear example..

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("htmysite.com");
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
cookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("rrrr.it"), @"_sdsfdsdsf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the job (it uses `HttpClient` not `HttpWebRequest` though). Just amend it to meet your needs.

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(
    Uri uri,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null,
    IEnumerable<Cookie> cookies = null)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
        {
            parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            if (cookies != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                {
                    handler.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                }
            }

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters))
                {
                    return await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But my doubt is on how to use the real values I wrote.. they are as many value as every = sign? or they can go all together in one cookie?

Comment: Each one is a different cookie. You'll need to find the appropriate cookie that controls the authentication (likely `authCookie` from what you've posted), and then find a way to obtain a valid value for that cookie.

Comment: mmm... not very clear.. can you make me an example of how to use one of that cookie to access, for example, forum.mysite.com?

Comment: Can you not follow the code? It accepts `Cookie` objects as a parameter. Try it out and instantiate a cookie appropriately yourself.

Comment: cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("__cfduid", "d16254")); => An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: the parameter '{0}' cannot be an empty string

Comment: Found.. it's really counterintuitive.. it's: cookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://mysite"), new Cookie(("__cfduid", "d16254"));

Comment: mmm... it still don't work, I'm not logged in.. is it usually a cookie problem or it can depend also on what I accept and so on?

Comment: Depends on the session lifetime of the authentication cookies. You might also need the session cookie too.

Comment: thanks for the patience.. Can I tell my cookie to last forever or is chosen serverside? How should it look like a session cookie? Or better question, how do I get them through fiddler? I've seen this two cookies are changing a few bytes from time to time: __utmb and authCookie

Comment: authCookie will depend on any given site's implementation - it's up to them. _utm* cookies are from Google Analytics. I can't help you any more I'm afraid.